# Как сделать update данных в xml

Tags: c#, xml, unity3d

Прошу помочь.
Надо проапдейтить данные в xml файле

```
<locations>
  <location id="1">
    <level name="1" complete="True" stars="0" firstMisson="False" secondMission="False" thridMission="False" />
  </location>
</locations>
```

Вот метод для update

```
        public void Update()
            {
                string filepath = Application.dataPath + @"/XML/GameXMLdata.xml";
                Debug.Log("come");
                bool completV = true;
                int stars = 3;
                bool fm = true; 
                bool sm = true;
                bool tm = true;

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
                IEnumerable<XElement> rech =
                                     from el in doc.Root.Elements("location")
                                     where el.Element("location").Attribute("id").Value == "1" // Ругается на эту строку
                                                //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
                                                //SelectorLogic.<Update>m__0 (System.Xml.Linq.XElement el) 
                                                //(at Assets/Scripts/SelectorLogic.cs:137)
                                     select el;
                if (rech.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (XElement el in rech)
                    {
                        if (el.Element("level").Attribute("name").Value == "1")
                        {
                            el.Element("level").Attribute("complete").Value = completV.ToString();
                            el.Element("level").Attribute("stars").Value = stars.ToString();
                            el.Element("level").Attribute("firstMisson").Value = fm.ToString();
                            el.Element("level").Attribute("secondMission").Value = sm.ToString();
                            el.Element("level").Attribute("thridMission").Value = tm.ToString();
                        }
                    }
             }
```

В чем проблема? Где мой косяк?

Comment: *"В чем проблема?"* - это вас надо спрашивать.

Comment: Как вариант, раздели свой LINQ запрос на несколько строк. Сначала сделай var tmp=doc.Root.Elements("location") и посмотри в дебагере что возвращается. И от этого плясать.

Comment: У вас же был класс из xml? У него поля помеченны как сериализующиеся. Вот и пишите. Зачем писать следующий вопрос если не закончили с предыдущим, а они у вас в сути своей одинаковые.

Comment: Если работает сериализация, то лучше этого не делать, а просто перезаписывать файл. Другого оптимального способа нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Update_Data_in_XML(any parametrs)
{
    string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + @"/data.xml";

    XmlDocument xmlData = new XmlDocument();
    xmlData.Load(filepath);

    XmlNode node;
    node = xmlData.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlNode node_location in node.ChildNodes)
        if (node_location.Name == "location" && node_location.Attributes["name"].Value == loc_name)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node_level in node_location.ChildNodes)
                if (node_level.Name == "level" && node_level.Attributes["name"].Value == lev_name)
                {
                    node_level.Attributes["complete"].Value = complete_level.ToString();

                    //other attributes
                    //...
                    //...

                    break;
                }
        }

    xmlData.Save(filepath);
}
```